# Will this adapter ring let me share filters between my lenses?

Tags: filters, adapter, filter-diameter

I have two lenses with 77m and 72mm filter sizes.I want to buy a ND filter of 77m .If I buy the adapter in below  will I be able to use the same filter with my lens with 72 mm filter ring?

[Adapter ring link](http://www.amazon.in/77mm-Cokin-Adapter-Filter-Holder/dp/B00DEI4HOA/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1377586706&sr=8-8&keywords=filter%20adapter%20ring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adapter you linked to allows using Cokin 'P' filters on a lens with 77mm filter threads. You could buy it plus another [adapter for your 72mm lens](http://www.amazon.in/72mm-Cokin-Adapter-Filter-Holder/dp/B00DEI4FM4/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1377594904&sr=8-4&keywords=cokin%20p%20filters) and then use a Cokin [P153](http://www.amazon.in/Cokin-P153-Neutral-Density-Filter/dp/B00004ZDBT) or [P154](http://www.amazon.in/Cokin-P154-Neutral-Density-Filter/dp/B0006ZSV1Y) ND filter for both. The square Cokin filters do not have threads, they are made to fit into the holder which needs the correct ring threaded to fit a specific lens thread size. Cokin also makes graduated ND filters sized in the 'P' series.

If you want to buy a 77mm threaded filter and also use it with a lens with 72mm filter threads what you need is a 72mm to 77mm step up ring such as [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002E3WKO) or [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/KENKO-72mm-77mm-Step-Up-Ring-Stepping-Adapter-72-77-Metal-Authorized-Dealer-/380692186802).